# Add a message on checkout page after (or if) a coupon is applied

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, coupon

I want to add a message on the checkout page either after (or if) a coupon is applied. The idea is to have a description of the promo and the bonus they get with the coupon.

```
add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'woocommerce_applied_coupon_action');
function woocommerce_applied_coupon_action($coupon_code)
{
    echo 'My Message';
}
```

Comment: May be this working answer [Replace "Coupon code applied successfully." Message in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235460/replace-coupon-code-applied-successfully-message-in-woocommerce/62236397#62236397) is what you are looking for.